# MPAndroidChart - Line Chart not showing line

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to build a LineChart with MPAndroidChart to represent the value I get from my decibel meter. The problem is that I only get a moving dot which represents current value but I'd like to have a line that, while moving, shows the values. Something like an EEG to be clear.

This is all the code related to the chart in onCreate() method:

```
chart.getDescription().setEnabled(true);
chart.getDescription().setText("Decibel chart");

chart.setTouchEnabled(false);
chart.setDragEnabled(false);
chart.setScaleEnabled(false);
chart.setPinchZoom(false);
chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

Legend l = chart.getLegend();
l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
l.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(100f);
leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);

chart.setDrawBorders(true);
```

These are the methods I use to update the data in my chart:

```
private LineDataSet createSet(List<Entry> entries) {
    LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(entries, "Decibel Data");
    set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    set.setLineWidth(4f);
    set.setColor(Color.RED);
    set.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
    set.setCubicIntensity(0.2f);

    return set;
}

private void updateChart(float x, float y) {

    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new Entry(x, y));

    if (entries.isEmpty()) {
        chart.clear();
    } else {
        LineDataSet lineDataSet = createSet(entries);
        LineData data = new LineData(lineDataSet);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        chart.setData(data);
        chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        chart.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Since I need to update my data dynamically, updateChart(float x, float y) is called from a thread.
This is what I see when I run my app:
[chart_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l2wP.png)

What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in following line:

```
List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
```

You create new arraylist whenever you receive update with one value. You need to declare entries on top of your activity before onCreate() as:

```
private List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
```

After that change your update method to:

```
private void updateChart(float x, float y) 
{
    entries.add(new Entry(x, y));
    LineDataSet lineDataSet = createSet(entries);
    LineData data = new LineData(lineDataSet);
    data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    chart.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Do let me know for further assistance. Happy coding!

Comment: When it works then check for if your list has no values and implement that check.